# session bind with @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have one of a method as following in my controller

Code

```
        var companies = ...
        List<CompanyModel> listOfCompanies = new List<CompanyModel>();

        foreach (var item in companies)
        {
             listOfCompanies.Add(new CompanyModel(item.CompanyId, item.CompanyName));
        }

        ViewBag.Company = listOfCompanies;
```

View page

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company, new SelectList(ViewBag.Company, "id", "name"), "Select company", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

this is working fine , I'm trying trying to use session instead of viewbag here.

So for that I did

```
        var companies = ...
        List<CompanyModel> listOfCompanies = new List<CompanyModel>();

        foreach (var item in companies)
        {
            listOfCompanies.Add(new CompanyModel(item.CompanyId, item.CompanyName));
        }

        Session["CompanyData"] = listOfCompanies;
```

View page

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company, new SelectList(Model.Company, "id", "name", Session["CompanyData"]), "Select company", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

but this is not working properly, whats the path to achieve this

Comment: What is property `Company`? You cannot use the same property for the property your binding to and the `SelectList`. But why are you using `Session` for this?

Comment: @StephenMuecke for this View page I'm using another model class, `Company` is one of property of that. I've to do this because I need to keep this  throughout few activities, after first invoke

Comment: One copy of it for each user? (`MemoryCache` would be more appropriate). In anycase, your controller methd should still retrieve it from `Session` and assign it to a `ViewBag` property (or better to a view model property).

Comment: And consider what happens if `Session` expires :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried simply replacing `ViewBag` with `Session`?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company, new SelectList((List<CompanyModel>)Session["CompanyData"], "id", "name"), "Select company", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: thats working , I have to give full path for `CompanyModel`